# TopApp Bar in windows 8 xaml

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, appbar

i am using app bar in multiple pages within my Windows 8 XAML application. I came to face some unusual problem with my app bar. For the first time, when I login to my application, the top app bar works fine, but when I logout and login to my app, the app bar gets disabled. I don't know what exactly the problem is, so couldn't state properly.

This problem exists on touch experience. It works fine if I use a mouse.

Comment: can you please upload source code ?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled: it doesn't appear or it appears but doesn't respond to user actions? Logging out and logging in to your application means the application is restarted in between or not?

Comment: it doesnot appear and the application is not restarted.. its between the process

Comment: What do you mean by "login/logout"?

Comment: please add more detail to the question, it is unclear